# Unable to call my own APIs from Dialogflow Fulfillment

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have my own API's developed which is running on my linux VM server, I am trying to call those APIs, from fulfillment with inline editor using axios and http , it was not able to hit the server which I confirmed in server logs, then  I tried with webhook, when I typed my URL , `<IP>:/xyz/` got the error

> Please use only public url

Can we call our own developed APIs from webhook?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the Inline Fulfillment Editor, your fulfillment is running on [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions). You can access your own APIs, however there is a limitation with the free tier of Firebase that restricts you to only accessing Google's network.

You can upgrade to the [Blaze plan](https://firebase.google.com/pricing) in Firebase. This does require you to have a card on file, but you're only charged for usage over a free tier - and that tier is more than suitable for typical development and even initial deployment.

If you wish this, you can setup fulfillment on any server you want, as long as it is accessible through a public HTTPS address without a self-signed certificate.